# Android: How to implement audio effects to a stream?

Tags: android, audio, effect, equalizer

I want to implement an application that applies audio effect such as increasing Bass frequency for input/output stream on API9+ (android2.3+). So my question is

Question 1: Where should I start? I'm now looking in [Equalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) and [AudioFX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html) for tutorial. But its examples don't work with me in this case.

Question 2: Is it possible for applying audio effect for whole input/output streams?

Looking for any suggestion, 
Many Thanks

Comment: Agreed, the AudioFX libraries in Android seem extremely unreliable.